# How can I ReadAllByte with unique Volume ID in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I tried this command, it's working fine:

```
$path = "C:\sometext.txt"
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$path")
```

But when I tried to read all bytes of file in PowerShell with unique ID like this code it doesn't work:

```
$path =  "\\.\Volume{3386ab07-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\sometext.txt"
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$path")
```

I take unique ID with:

```
$listdrive = ""
$drivelistuniqueID = Get-Volume 
foreach ($item in $drivelistuniqueID)
{
    $listdrive += $item.UniqueId + "DriveLetterSplIttEr"
}
$listdrive=$listdrive.Replace("?",".")
$listdrive
```

If I don't replace `?` with `.` PowerShell says:

```
Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in
path."
At line:3 char:1
+ [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$path")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

Any idea about how I could fix this error? **I need only read file with GUID (Unique ID).**

Comment: So what is the question? "doesn't work" is quite vague, does it throw any errors?

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen : i write error . Exception calling... and u can try it too

Comment: Right, but you state that it also doesn't work when you replace `?` with `.` - what happens in that case?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen :powershell says Illegal characters in path

Comment: So you get the same error with both the path that starts with ``\\?\`` and ``\\.\``?

Comment: nope when i use \\.\ the error is Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of 
"\\.\" in the path."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125835/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-arashzgh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually when you want to read all byte you can do it directly . test this on your computer make new file wile using GUID then try to open file . you will see you can't . if you want to use  readallbyte you should hook this.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing file and device [namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#namespaces) there, and I'm not even sure if `System.IO.File` methods support namespaced paths at all. What are you trying to achieve anyway? If you want to read a file from a mounted volume, something like this should work:

```
$guid  = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
$drive = (Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.ObjectId -like "*$guid*"}).DriveLetter
$path  = Join-Path "${drive}:" 'sometext.txt'

$data = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($path)
```

If the drive hasn't been mounted you probably need to mount it first.

```
Get-Volume |
  Where-Object {$_.ObjectId -like "*$guid*"} |
  Get-Partition |
  Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter X
```

I don't think you can access files via `System.IO.File` on an unmounted volume.

Comment: i have access when i write get-childitem "\\.\Volume{3386ab07-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\sometext.txt" i can get directory